# Long path issue occurred while try to install Nuget package in Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, manage-nuget-packages

I have worked on dot net core projects. while trying to install NuGet packages in my project with the help of manage NuGet packages option, I have faced below mentioned error. Could you please suggest the solution for this issue?

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Don't try to put your project in deep nested folder like this: D:\MyApp\PracticeApp\Projects\FinalSubmission. Simplify your path and keep it simple like ths: D:\MyApp\FinalSubmission.

Comment: Yes, I have tried with this folder structure (D:\T\ProjectFile) also but still, I have faced same issue. Could you please suggest, there is any solution to accept the long path?